# 2 "style" inline css img tags?

Tags: html, css

I have the following tag

```
<img src="http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/119/original120x75.png"style="height:100px;" 
style="width:100px;" alt="25"/>
```

I have put two incline CSS commands in

```
style="width:100px;"
style="height:100px;"
```

For some reason the picture has 100px height but no width.
I assume this is because you can't write two of these in a row in the same tag.
If this is true, is there a way to assign both the height and width?
I have already assigned a different image size on my external CSS, and I don't think you can add `img` properties in the `div` tag properties on the external CSS.
thanks

Comment: You should be able to put both of the styles in the same style tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need 2 style attributes - just use one:

```
<img src="http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/119/original120x75.png" 
                                     style="height:100px;width:100px;" alt="25"/>
```

Consider, however, using a CSS class instead:

CSS:

```
.100pxSquare
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/119/original120x75.png" 
                                          class="100pxSquare" alt="25"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use more than one style attribute. Just seperate styles in the style attribute with `;`
It is a block of inline CSS, so think of this as you would do CSS in a separate stylesheet.

So in this case its: 
`style="height:100px;width:100px;"`

You can use this for any CSS style, so if you wanted to change the colour of the text to white:
`style="height:100px;width:100px;color:#ffffff"` and so on.

However, it is worth using inline CSS sparingly, as it can make code less manageable in future. Using an external stylesheet may be a better option for this. It depends really on your requirements. Inline CSS does make for quicker coding.

Answer (score 3):

You should use :

```
<img src="http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/119/original120x75.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" alt="25"/>
```

That should work!!

If you want to create class then :

```
.size {
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

and then apply it like :

```
<img src="http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/119/original120x75.png" class="size" alt="25"/>
```

by creating a class you can use it at multiple places.

If you want to use only at one place then use inline CSS.
Also Inline CSS overrides other CSS.

Answer (score 1):

**if use Inline CSS you use**

```
<img src="http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/119/original120x75.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" alt="705"/>
```

Otherwise you can use class properties which related with a separate css file (styling your website) as like
**In CSS File**

```
.imgSize {height:100px;width:100px;}
```

**In HTML File**

```
<img src="http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/119/original120x75.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;" alt="705"/>
```