# Wordpress <img> style is being overridden when placed in widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress, barcode, barcode-printing

I am creating a WP Widget that draws a barcode. I can generate a barcode that works just fine when I just place it on an admin page (à la Hello Dolly!).

[image]

The  tags that make up the barcode explicitly set the height and width of the bars and spaces and everyone is happy.

When I apply the same plug-in code to a widget, the width is left alone, but the height is scaled down for some reason.

[image]

The result is a barcode approximately 1 pixel high which doesn't scan right. I am interested in finding out why / how my explicit styling is being overridden in the widget class.

EDIT: The only css contained in the plug-in is here:

```
// We need some CSS to position the paragraph
function barcode_css() {
        $x = is_rtl() ? 'left' : 'right';

        echo "
        <style type='text/css'>
        #barcode {
                float: $x;
                padding-$x: 15px;
                padding-top: 5px;
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 11px;
        }
        </style>
        ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. Instead of trying explicitly set  attributes for height and width I used inline CSS according to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15000373/769938

Once I adjusted my widget's php it started working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding !important to your css?

Comment: I got it working. Your suggestion put me on the right path, but I did not need to use !important. I used inline style instead of trying to set the height and width attributes directly and relying on css to sort things out.

Comment: This is not really the best answer to the question. Try to avoid ```!important``` in your style, unless it's the only possible way. Read about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css#answer-3706876